# Writing email messages to flat files in Outlook with VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, flat-file

I have written a VBA app that opens a folder in outlook and then iterates through the messages.  I need to write the message bodies (with some tweaking) to a single flat file.  My code is as follows...

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click()
    Dim objOutlook As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objInbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim objMail As mailItem
    Dim count As Integer

    Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objInbox = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    count = 0

    For Each objMail In objInbox.Items
       lblStatus.Caption = "Count: " + CStr(count)
       ProcessMailItem (objMail)
       count = count + 1
    Next objMail

  End If
End Sub
```

The part in question is "ProcessMailItem".  As I am not overly concerned with performance at this stage so the very inefficent "open, append, close" file methodology is fine for this example.

I know I could spend some time looking up the answer with google but I checked here first and there was no good answers for this.  Being a fan of Stackoverflow I hope that putting this up here will help future developers looking for answers.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get away with writing to a file without using any objects, just using the built in VBA file tools:

```
Open "C:\file.txt" for append as 1
Print #1, SomeStringVar
Close #1
```

Comment: I chose this answer because it is very VBA centric. Eric Ness' answer is also valid!!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind re-opening the output file each time you append some text, then this should work.

```
Private Sub ProcessMailItem(objMail As MailItem)

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream

    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Outputfile.txt", ForAppending, True)

    ts.Write(objMail.Body)

    ts.Close()
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

You'll also need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library.  This has  FileSystemObject in it.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to take care of the security popup "trying to access email addresses" which is covered in [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52)

```
Public Sub ProcessMailItem(objMail As MailItem)
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim loc As String
Dim subject As String
Dim strID As String
' per http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
subject = oMail.subject
Set ts = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\tempuser\My Documents\EMAILS\" + subject, ForAppending, True)
ts.Write (oMail.Body)
ts.Close
Set ts = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: there's still some issue with the path in the OpenTextFile. i don't get consistent results to that path vs a shorter path with no spaces.